# How to insert and resize image in a table cell in header in Word using c#?

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop

I have this method which inserts the header in my document.
I want to insert a picture in the first cell of the table in the header. Also I want to type a line of text under that image but in the same cell.
However I get an error at "shape.Width = 60;" and crashes Word. Can someone help me?

```
public void insertHeader()
    {

        foreach (Word.Section section in ObjDoc.Sections)
        {
            Word.Table TablaHdr;
            Word.Range headerRange = section.Headers[Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range;
            TablaHdr = ObjDoc.Tables.Add(headerRange, 1, 2, ref ObjMiss, ref ObjMiss);

            TablaHdr.Columns[1].SetWidth(ObjWord.MillimetersToPoints(57.9f), Word.WdRulerStyle.wdAdjustNone);
            TablaHdr.Columns[2].SetWidth(ObjWord.MillimetersToPoints(98.1f), Word.WdRulerStyle.wdAdjustNone);

            TablaHdr.Borders[Word.WdBorderType.wdBorderHorizontal].Visible = true;
            TablaHdr.Borders[Word.WdBorderType.wdBorderVertical].Visible = true;
            TablaHdr.Borders[Word.WdBorderType.wdBorderTop].Visible = true;
            TablaHdr.Borders[Word.WdBorderType.wdBorderLeft].Visible = true;
            TablaHdr.Borders[Word.WdBorderType.wdBorderRight].Visible = true;
            TablaHdr.Borders[Word.WdBorderType.wdBorderBottom].Visible = true;


            var shape = TablaHdr.Cell(1,1).Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(@"D:\logo.png", false, true);
            shape.Width=60;
            shape.Height=60;

        }
    }
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in PruebaActa1.exe Additional information: Error en la llamada a procedimiento remoto. (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x800706BE)